# Vuejs - Read a txt content

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying read txt content and put in a string. The file is in the .src folder of the vuejs project.

how can I do this?

I tried 
`var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
  XHR.open("GET", "notificion.txt", true);
  XHR.send();`

but doesn´t work

Comment: please always provide code... stackoverflow does not contain magicians. Thank you

Comment: You are still not clear bro.. i wanna help

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `raw-loader`.

```
npm install raw-loader --save-dev
```

Then you can import raw `.txt` file like below;

```
import RawText from 'raw-loader!./rawText.txt'
```

Or, edit webpack config like below;

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.txt$/i,
        use: 'raw-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Then you can import like `import RawText from './rawText.txt'`

For more information -> [webpack-contrib/raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader)

Comment: add in my webpack rules: [
      {
        test: /\.txt$/i,
        use: 'raw-loader'
      }
    ], and import txt from 'raw-loader!./text.txt' in my componet, but 
give the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export